# single 4 pin cpu power cord in a 4+4 pin psu connector input

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, computer-building

I have a corsair hx 1200 power supply ... my crosshair vIII hero motherboard has 2 cpu inputs on it... one 8 pin and one 4 pin... i ordered custom cables from cablemod as well... one 8 pin and one 4 pin... but now that im looking at the power supply there is no spot for just one 4 pin.. can i plug the single 4 pin into the power supply by itself in the middle of the 4+4 input on the power supply... or do i find a way to plug the single 4 pin into one side or the other 4+4 pin input?

Answer (score 0):

If you go and read the manual, it's clearly stated what you need to do.

[image]

https://www.corsair.com/corsairmedia/sys_master/productcontent/HX_Manual.pdf